# Difference in use between "geodetic" and "geodesic" terms

Tags: word-usage, terminology

I usually write questions and answers on https://gis.stackexchange.com.

English is not my first language, and every time I have to write any of these terms I come back into doubt about which of the two corresponds.

A geodesic, can be understood as the shortest path (contained in a curved surface) between two points. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)

But I have the problem when I have to refer to something related to geodesy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy), e.g., *"geodesic distance"*, *"geodesic calculations"*, *"geodesic math"*, *"direct geodetic problem"*, *"geodetic datum"*, *"geodetic coordinates"*.

I don't know which of the two terms I should use.

What is specifically the use that should be given to the terms "geodetic" and "geodesic"?

Comment: I'm a native speaker _and_ a software engineer with significant GIS experience, and I often wonder the same thing. I do think this question is a better fit for gis.stackexchange.com as it's really about technical jargon, not the English language itself.

Comment: @TypeIA Thank you for the response. The question was raised in the chat room there, but the room is not very busy. I will make sure that it is not considered off topic if it is posed as a question on the GIS SE site. It is likely that there would be read by people focused on the subject, but I thought the topic was more suitable for this site.

Comment: Possibly relevant Q&A on the GIS site: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/25982/57394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too frequent the GIS Stack Exchange and use English as my first language in Australia.

I was not sure of the answer so I used search terms of "adjective geodesy" to find this [Dictionary.com definition for geodetic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/geodetic):

> **geodetic** [jee-uh-det-ik]
>
> *adjective*
>
> 1. pertaining to geodesy.
> 2. geodesic.

It looks like geodetic and geodesic mean the same thing and are equally valid to use.  My preference is to use geodetic as the adjective of geodesy.

Answer (score 1):

**Geodesy**

Geodesy (from greek γεω- geo- and δαι ́ζω split) relates to the study of Earth shape.

A geodesic line is a [shortest possible path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid) on an [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) like Earth, what we commonly call a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle), though this word only applies to a perfect sphere.

[Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Simon_Laplace) first defined the geodesic line as [ligne géodésique](https://books.google.com/books?id=5FKKk5EGLJ8C&pg=PA112):

> Nous désignerons cette ligne sous le nom de ligne géodésique.

**Confusion**

A confusion was created a long time ago when the *geodesic line* concept was translated into English by English scientists like [Hutton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Hutton) who proposed a [translation of his own](https://books.google.com/books?id=CjRRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22line%20traced%20in%20the%20manner%20%22):

> A line traced in the manner we have now been describing, or deduced from trigonometrical measures, by the means we have indicated, is called a geodetic or geodesic line.

This gave:

- [Struve Geodetic Arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_Geodetic_Arc), a survey triangulation chain, obviously related to geodesy.
- ArcGIS using the [geodetic](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/about-geodetic-features.htm) line alternative.

**Geodetic datum**

There is a special case where the word *geodetic* is the only one used. A [geodetic datum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum) is a datum used in geodesy and other fields. The best known being [WGS 84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) used for all [GNSS techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation), WGS meaning World Geodetic System.

For other uses, geodesic and geodetic are synonymous, the result of this double translation.